# How to hide Passwords in Sql Server Table from others

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a column that holds a password..i want to do is simply mask the password with the standard password character (*) or Simply hide...

Thanks in advance....

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: You CAN NOT use star (*) but you CAN store password encrypted

Comment: [Don't store passwords in plain text](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html)

Comment: Under what conditions?  You could create a view that offers a column with the same length as the password, but filled with asterisks.  Or, better yet, a constant number of asterisks so as not to reveal anything helpful to the evil among us.  If you really want to hide the password with asterisks then add a trigger that always replaces the passwords with asterisks.  Problem solved!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LOL, This is not possible. You can't modify the way Management Studio shows a table!

However, usually, you don't store passwords in DDBB, but the hash.

See this:

http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2009/09/19/strong-password-hashing-with-sql-server.aspx

Comment: And you *must* use a salt, or someone with access to the database can very easily plop their own password into the place of the other user, log in as that user, then restore the user's hash. While of course the back-end access allows messing with stuff directly, it could be very hard to duplicate the application's actual own actions. Even not knowing the hashing algorithm, without salts there is another vector possible to discover a user's password by changing one's own password in a brute force attack until the database is observed to have a hash that matches someone else's password.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the Hashing Method,read this article (specific to MySQL)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html

Comment: You assume that he is actually writing an app others need to authenticate to.  What if he is writing a username/password store app like keypass? (note: I didn't downvote)

Comment: He tagged it with SQL Server, why give a MySQL answer?

Comment: Yes I was assuming that.But here some persons are TOO SMART and loves to make feel other helpers like dumbs (I'm talking to the downvoter).

Comment: Hashing is the same,everywhere (anyway sorry,i thought it was mysql).

Comment: "Hashing is the same". Maybe, but function names not. And It wasn't me the down-voter.